# How do I make imageView look better

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a  android  imageview   and its working perfectly fine.The only problem is it doesnot look good.I want to make UI like flicker UI where images are shown in a nice way.

1)How do i make it look better?

2)Are there any open src libs for this?

Comment: @reto :Why not?I am a java dev and i suck at UI but i have to make it.I am asking how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to show multiple images in your activity. There are many libraries available

- 1. https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
  2. https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

But before using these you have to take care of laoding Bitmaps efficiently. Large images shown in small imageview is a waste of memory.

Check developer docs for this -

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html